# Find location by latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql

I have seen lots of post about the searching location through geo location and latitude.

I tried to search by mysql query. But none of the query giving the perfect result. 
Here is my query, it does not return the perfect result.

```
SELECT *, 
    ( 3959 * 
        acos(
            cos( radians('"+user.getGeoLocationLatitude()+"') ) * 
            cos( radians( geoLocationLatitude ) ) * 
            cos( radians( geoLocationLongitude ) - radians('"+user.getGeoLocationLongitude()+"') ) + 
            sin( radians('"+user.getGeoLocationLatitude()+"') ) * 
            sin( radians( geoLocationLatitude ) ) ) 
        ) AS distance 
        FROM user 
        HAVING distance < '"+user.getDistance()+"' 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 20"
    );
```

Please anyone give me some ideas..

Comment: What is your definition of a "perfect result"?

Comment: Suppose distance between A and B is 70 mile. Suppose i searching 55 mile from A, then B should not come i  the result. But it comes.

Comment: Giving actual example coordinates of such a case would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the HTML5 GeoLocation API can help you better. follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_geolocation.asp)!